# How to create a Cocos2d project

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

Which Cocos2d version is the "best" to download (most reliable)?

And how to step by step download Cocos2d and create a Cocos2d Xcode project. (When I do it, I end up with over 200 errors)

Answer (score 1):

Download the latest stable version which is 3.4 through SpriteBuilder. SpriteBuilder can be downloaded on the Mac App Store. All the information for downloading previous archives can be found [here](http://cocos2d.spritebuilder.com/download).

Comment: But when I do this I can't use things like `CCLayer` like they do in raywenderlich tutorials. How an I use these feature?

Comment: @Minestroni-Soup the tutorial (cocos2d v2.x) is out of date with respect to SpriteBuilder (cocos2d v3.4). Snare out a tutorial for v3.x from Ray's site.